# Transposing - Switching Rows & Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to transpose row and column, but have no idea how this can be done.

**Here is the data sheet with the raw data and desired output:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HLBSCdziga3gJtCkNEpx-paFO9eHHYJy/view?usp=sharing

- Keep the "Date" column as it is and changed "Source: Email", "Source: Social", and "Source: Display" columns to rows
- Action rows (Scroll, Click, Swipe) now need to be changed to columns
- Moreover, I would like to create a new column to add all the actions.

Is this something that I can do using Python (pandas)? I would appreciate it if you could help me on this.

Thank you so much in advance!
Tae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution might be slightly juggly:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('A/tab/separated/file/with/your/data.tsv')

#Stack your columns as an extra index, then unstack one of your indexes into columns
reshaped_df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Website Action']).stack().unstack(level=1).fillna(0).reset_index()

# Rename the columns, calculate total engagements
reshaped_df.columns = ['Date','Source','Click','Scroll','Swipe']
reshaped_df['Total Engagements'] = reshaped_df[['Click','Scroll','Swipe']].sum(axis=1)
```

So long story short, yep, pandas can do it, the above is one example of how. I would recommend running every bit of this in an interactive shell (check out what happens when you apply set_index, what happens when you stack or unstack).

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "Date": ["10/1/2018","10/2/2018","10/2/2018","10/3/2018"],
               "Website Action" : ["Scroll","Scroll","Click","Swipe"],
               "Source:Email" : [1,1,3,2],
               "Source:Social" : [4,2,10,6],
               "Source:Display" : [5,3,3,9]})
```

just setting up your example frame (order of columns a bit off):

```
    Date    Source:Display  Source:Email    Source:Social   Website Action
0   10/1/2018   5   1   4   Scroll
1   10/2/2018   3   1   2   Scroll
2   10/2/2018   3   3   10  Click
3   10/3/2018   9   2   6   Swipe
```

You can now combine "melt" and "pivot_table" to get what you want:

```
df.melt(id_vars=["Date","Website Action"]).pivot_table(index = ["Date","variable"], columns = "Website Action").fillna(0)
```

this yields:

```
        value
Website Action  Click   Scroll  Swipe
Date    variable            
10/1/2018   Source:Display  0.0 5.0 0.0
            Source:Email    0.0 1.0 0.0
            Source:Social   0.0 4.0 0.0
10/2/2018   Source:Display  3.0 3.0 0.0
            Source:Email    3.0 1.0 0.0
            Source:Social   10  2.0 0.0
10/3/2018   Source:Display  0.0 0.0 9.0
            Source:Email    0.0 0.0 2.0
            Source:Social   0.0 0.0 6.0
```

reordering and renaming i leave up to you :-)

Comment: This may be a stupid question. But how does "variable" work in the melt equation?